# Passing object from one window to another window

Tags: javascript

I know this question had been asked many times in here, i tried each one of it but it just couldn't work.

I have a website application hosted under https://app.yyy.com, and another one which is basically just a receipt template, which i put inside the mine.com web server. The receipt template has its own script on it, and its URL is https://yyy.com/receipt/receiptTemplate.html. I'm telling all these details because i read that templates that are hosted under the same domain may be subjected to CORS issue when trying to pass data from one window to another.

My requirement is to pass data object from the website application to the receipt template, in which the script will get the object data and render it to the template.

I have the following in the wesbite application script, which is to make a call to fetch data, and open up the receipt template upon successful call. I also tried to attach the data by using window.opener (as suggested by one of the answer that i found in here.

```
$.get('/getdata', function(data) {
    var invoice = window.open('https://yyy.com/receipt/receiptemplate.html');
    window.opener.receiptdata = data;
});
```

And on the receipt script, i have the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = window.receiptdata;
    generateReceipt(data);
});
```

But the above couldn't work.

I tried the following with localStorage this time, also suggested by the answer that i found in here..

```
$.get('/getdata', function(data) {
    var invoice = window.open('https://yyy.com/receipt/receiptemplate.html');
    localStorage.setItem('receiptdata', data);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = localStorage.getItem('receiptdata');
    generateReceipt(data);
});
```

But didn't work too.

I dunno how else can i pass the object data to the other page... =(

Comment: @djfdev problem is that, the template is totally outside of the project folder (can be hosted elsewhere too if needed that is not within yyy.com), and the API is from the project. We don't plan on opening the API, so totally cannot make ajax call from the receipt template.

Comment: Sorry, moved my comment to an answer but then saw your explanation. In that case yes, you will be restricted by the CORS policy.

Comment: So meaning to say, if that template is hosted elsewhere that is not yyy.com, will it work @djfdev ?

Comment: If the template is served from the same origin (protocol + host + port) as the API, then it will work. But if the origin of the receipt template is different than the API, it will not work and you will have to enable CORS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a *typo* to begin with: `window` in `window.opener.receiptdata = data;`  is your current window, you want to access the window object you just created: `invoice`.

```
$.get('/getdata', function(data) {
  var invoice = window.open(generateURL(), '');
  invoice.receiptdata = data;
}
```

[As a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c13esfwu/)  since StackSnippets won't allow popups.

But for this to work, since you are hosting the two pages on different subdomains, you may need to [change their origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Changing_origin):

```
document.domain = 'yyy.com';
```

---

---

Now, if these were hosted on completely different domains, you would have to use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage):

```
var invoice = window.open('https://yyy.com/receipt/receiptemplate.html');
invoice.postMessage(receiptdata, 'app.yyy');
```

and in your template

```
addEventListener('message', e => {
  if(e.origin === 'http://app.yyy.com') {
    window.receiptdata = e.data;
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried the idea for the postMessage, and it works. But will that be okay since technically both pages are from the same domains. Also what should i put on my targetOrigin parameter for the postMessage if i want to use this approach?

Comment: @FredA postMessage works crossorigin. Generally you'd put the true document's origin, or a wildcard `"*"`